# Tomcat started / stopped with error, return code 1

Tags: installation, tomcat, jdk, jre, stack

"   Make sure you have java JDK or JRE installed and the required ports are free
Check the ""/xampp/tomcat/logs"folder for more information   "
Tell me in detail plz.

Comment: You need to provide more details, like well have you installed JDK or JRE? Or what OS are you using, or what else did you install on it? With the little info you gave, nobody can really help you.